# Stream Closed in WorkbookFactory.create(stream) Apache POI

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-poi

I created a 'ResetOnCloseInputStream' which extends BufferedInputStream, because I'm passing it to WorkbookFactory.create(InputStream) and it closes the stream after reading workbook, whereas I need to use the stream again. ResetOnInputStream looks like this-

```
public class ResetOnCloseInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {

private final InputStream decorated;

public ResetOnCloseInputStream(InputStream anInputStream) {
    super(anInputStream);
    if (!anInputStream.markSupported()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("marking not supported");
    }

    anInputStream.mark( 1 << 24); // magic constant: BEWARE
    decorated = anInputStream;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    decorated.reset();
}
public void realClose() throws IOException {
    decorated.close();
}

@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    return decorated.read();
}
}
```

but when it's passed to

```
workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(stream);
```

I get this error-

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:308)
```

Comment: Why do you use `decorated` if you are already inheriting from `BufferedInputStream`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I found an example which inherited from InputStream and changed it to BufferedInputStream.

Comment: cant you just reopen the stream again afterwards? or use a TeeInputStream, see e.g. http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the exception with your given class `ResetOnCloseInputStream`

```
    File inputFile = new File("C:/Test/Test.xls");
    FileInputStream fileInput;
    try {
        fileInput = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        BufferedInputStream bufferInput = new ResetOnCloseInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fileInput));
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(bufferInput);
        Sheet s1 = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        System.out.println(s1.getSheetName()); //Sheet1
    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I guess the problem may come the InputStream `stream` you created, it may be closed before passing to `WorkbookFactory.create(bufferInput)`.